# Beanstalkc Timeout Question

Tags: python, beanstalkd, beanstalkc

I am using beanstalkc in Python for a queuing process for a program which has to parse a list of URLs. Hence I am using timeout in beanstalk for avoiding huge time consumption by any URL. But even after using it my process doesn't time out in the limit and is taking a lot of time for parsing few URLs. I am using the following code:

```
for seed in seedlist:
    print 'Put data: %s' % seed
    bean.put(seed,ttr =5)
while True: 
    job = bean.reserve() 
    spider.spider(job.body)
    print 'Got data: %s' % job.body
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of beanstalkd's TTR timeouts. Quoting the [beanstalkd FAQ](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/faq):

> **How does TTR work**
>
> TTR only applies to a job at the moment it becomes reserved. At that event, a timer (called “time-left” in the job stats) starts counting down from the job’s TTR.
>
> - If the timer reaches zero, the job gets put back in the ready queue.
> - If the job is buried, deleted, or released before the timer runs out, the timer ceases to exist.
> - If the job is "touch"ed before the timer reaches zero, the timer starts over counting down from TTR.
>
> (The job stats of a job that isn’t reserved still contain a “time-left” entry, but its value is meaningless.)

So the TTR does *not* help you in "avoiding huge time consumption by any URL". It does not magically kill your worker processes. All it does is that beanstalkd puts a job back into the queue, if a worker doesn't mark the job as finished after a given timespan (the TTR).